apt-add-repository needs to run twice on debian 12
I am trying to install qgis on debian bookworm. However when adding the repository the new source is not recognized:
add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/${os} ${release} main" && apt-get update

Repository: 'deb https://qgis.org/debian bookworm main'
Description:
Archive for codename: bookworm components: main
More info: https://qgis.org/debian
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-bookworm.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-bookworm.list
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

Also apt-cache shows an outdated version which is not from https://qgis.org/.
However, when running add-apt-repository a second time it works?!
root@ddc3e7ea6d37:/# add-apt-repository "deb https://qgis.org/${os} ${release} main" && apt-get update
    
Repository: 'deb https://qgis.org/debian bookworm main'
Description:
Archive for codename: bookworm components: main
More info: https://qgis.org/debian
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-bookworm.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-bookworm.list
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease         
Get:1 https://debian.qgis.org/debian bookworm InRelease [5482 B]     
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Get:5 https://debian.qgis.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [58.8 kB]
Fetched 64.3 kB in 0s (160 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease 
Hit:2 https://debian.qgis.org/debian bookworm InRelease             
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

I need to create a Docker image with qgis so running the command twice seems not to be a good way.
Do you have any idea why this is happening?
Edit:
After the first run /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_qgis_org_debian-bookworm.list is empty. After the second run it contains:
deb https://qgis.org/debian bookworm main
# deb-src https://qgis.org/debian bookworm main


This is a known issue, the workaround is to run add-apt-repository twice, as you discovered.
As an aside, you don’t need to run apt-get update manually, add-apt-repository updates the caches itself.
